# Максимум два запроса одновременно в HttpClient

Tags: c#, http, io

Почему `HttpClient` создает только два соединения для нескольких запросов на один домен одновременно? Например такой код

```
static string[] urls = new string[]
{
    "http://site.com/a",
    "http://site.com/b",
    "http://site.com/c",
    "http://site.com/d",
};

static void Main()
{
    var hc = new HttpClient();
    var list = new List<Task<string>>();
    foreach (var item in urls)
    {
        list.Add(hc.GetStringAsync(item));
    }
    Task.WaitAll(list.ToArray());
}
```

приведет к такому результату
[image: два соединения]

из-за чего весь процесс будет медленнее, так как надо подождать завершение какого-либо из двух запросов, чтоб начать третий

Хотя если изменить запросы на разные домены

```
static string[] urls = new string[]
{
    "http://sitea.com/",
    "http://siteb.com/",
    "http://sitec.com/",
    "http://sited.com/",
};
```

,то

[image: fine]

Почему так происходит, почему именно только два одновременно, как решить это?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2960056/trying-to-run-multiple-http-requests-in-parallel-but-being-limited-by-windows

Comment: @PrimusSingularis, не могу понять, как тогда помогает создание многих `HttpClient`'ов?

Comment: @Qutrix скорее всего создание новый HttpClient вызывает сборку мусора и dispose старых HttpClient (их кстати положено руками диспоузить)

Comment: @PashaPash, не очень понимаю как это связано

Comment: @Qutrix вродебы раньше настройки из ServicePointManager ограничивали общее количество подключений, а не только из одного HttpClient. вполне могу ошибаться.

Comment: @PashaPash, да, вполне возможно: посмотрел исходники `HttpClient`, он создает свой `ConnectionGroup`, которым пользуется  `ServicePoint`, что позволяет ограничить количество подключений на объект `HttpClient`, а не на общее. Возможно раньше этого не было

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте изменить значение ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit

[Managing Connections](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7af54za5(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: да, это сработало, но остался вопрос: как тогда помогает создание многих `HttpClient`'ов?

Comment: @Qutrix ограничение работает на одного клиента, по поводу того зачем это сделано, можете почитать дискуссию тут https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/2332, то что касается RFC 2616

Answer (score 0):

Если верить MSDN то проблема в том что сама OS WINDOWS ограничивает количество одновременных запросов на сервисы на базе HTTP 1.0 количеством 4 штуки и на HTTP 1.1 до двух штук.

Для исправления этой ситуации вам необходимо перейти в регистр (Win+R -> regedit)
Найти ветку HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\
Internet Settings

и добавить две переменные (или изменить имеющиеся)

MaxConnectionsPerServer = для http 1.1
и MaxConnectionsPer1_0Server для http 1.0, которые установлены на 2 и 4 соответсвенно.

Comment: изменил, запустил - не помогло, все так же 2. Да и не кажется что проблема в этом, так как если сделать много `HttpClient`'ов, то будет много одновременных соединений даже на один домен